# Suggestion list doesn't update correctly after adding new element using react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a list in array like,

```
ReactDOM.render(<FilteredList labelInfo = { labelArr } />, document.getElementById('labels'));
```

and data in array is,

```
labelArr.push({ "Label": "abc", "id": "a.dfg", "src_tbl": "d_v" });
```

React function is as,

```
var FilteredList = React.createClass({
                filterList: function(event) {
                    var updatedList = this.state.initialItems[0];
                    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item) {
                        return (item.Label.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || item.id.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
                    });
                    this.setState({items: updatedList});
                    LabelList = updatedList;
                },
                getInitialState: function() {
                    LabelList = this.props.labelInfo;
                    return {
                      initialItems: [ this.props.labelInfo ]
                    }
                },
                componentWillMount: function() {
                    this.setState({items: this.state.initialItems[0]})
                },
                newAddedLabel: function(e) {
                    //some code..
                    LabelList.push({ "Label": $('#lbl_txt').val(), "id": labelId , "type": "text"});
                    <List items={LabelList} />
                    //this.state.initialItems[0] = LabelList;
                    this.setState({items: LabelList});
                },
                changedLabel: function(e) {
                    //some code..
                    if( labelIndex > -1 )
                    {
                        LabelList[labelIndex].Label = $('#changelbl_txt').val();
                        LabelList[labelIndex].id = $('#changelbl_id').val();
                    }
                    <List items={LabelList} />
                    //this.state.initialItems[0] = LabelList;
                    this.setState({items: LabelList});
                },
                render: function() {
                    return (
                        <div className="filter-list">
                            <input 
                              type="text" 
                              id="searchBox"
                              placeholder="Search"
                              onChange={this.filterList}/>
                              <i 
                                className="fa fa-plus addLabel"  
                                title="Add a new label" 
                                id="add_label" 
                                onClick={this.addLabel}>
                              </i>
                              <List items={LabelList}/>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            });
```

`addLabel` call `newAddedLabel()` and add new values in it.. The main problem is when I started searching in input box, it makes a list of suggestions list(which shows on typing in inputbox) and save in a `LabelList`and then if I add a new value by clicking in `fa-plus` it shows only suggested list only instead of whole list..how can I display whole list when new label is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the filterList function onChange

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterList}/>
```

inside this function you are changing the state of initialItems

```
var updatedList = this.state.initialItems[0];
```

This why after you put some value inside the input your initialItems change, make a clone of this array like this:

```
var updatedList = this.state.initialItems[0].slice();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
<div id='root'></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  
  var FilteredList = React.createClass({
                filterList: function(event) {
                    if(event.target.value.trim() === ''){ 
                      this.setState({ suggest: [] })
                      return
                    }
                    
                    var updatedList = this.state.initialItems.slice();
                    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item) {
                        return (item.Label.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || item.id.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
                    });
                    
                    this.setState({suggest: updatedList || []});
                },
                getInitialState: function() {
                    return {
                      initialItems: [ this.props.labelInfo ],
                      items: [ this.props.labelInfo ],
                      suggest: [],
                      id: 1
                    }
                },
                newAddedLabel: function(e) {
                    
                    var newId= ++this.state.id + ""
                    var item = { "Label": this.refs.keyword.value, "id": newId , "type": "text"}  
                    var newItems = this.state.initialItems.slice()
                    newItems.push(item)
                    var newItems2 = this.state.items.slice()
                    newItems2.push(item)
                    
                    this.setState({initialItems: newItems, items: newItems2 });
                },
                
                render: function() {
                    return (
                        <div className="filter-list">
                            <input 
                              type="text"
                              ref="keyword"
                              id="searchBox"
                              placeholder="Search"
                              onChange={this.filterList}/>
                              <button 
                                className="fa fa-plus addLabel"  
                                title="Add a new label" 
                                id="add_label" 
                                onClick={this.newAddedLabel}>Add
                              </button>
                              <u>{ this.state.suggest.map(e => <li value={e.id}>{e.Label}</li>) }</u>
                              <h1>Saved List</h1>
                              <u>{ this.state.items.map(e => <li value={e.id}>{e.Label}</li>) }</u>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            });
  
  ReactDOM.render(<FilteredList labelInfo = { { "Label": "abc", "id": "a.dfg", "src_tbl": "d_v" } }  />, document.getElementById('root'))
</script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I tried this but when I add a new label it doesn't update the list..I think main problem is when I search something and then add a new label  then it update list as a new suggestion list and doesn't show initial whole list..but I don't have an idea how to do

Comment: Yeah may b u r right.. I have to make a clone and then use this so that It doesn't effect on main list.. m i correct?

Comment: I just put an example to you because I don't understand what do you want to do. Hope this helps!

Comment: in this example if you add something and search that name it wasn't appear in suggested list as I need this exactly

Comment: ok, so just change the add function and add the item to suggest property. Well I'm deleting the suggest list every time, I guess with the example you have plenty of things to work, basically use a property to save the full suggest list and other to show the current suggest list. Let me know if you don't understand

Comment: can u make a snippet again plz.. I am not getting this

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130659/discussion-between-debin-and-damianfabian).

Comment: Sure tell me by the chat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that using the above code, you can have a boolean variable in your state which decides weather to render the suggested list or the initial list.

The in the render method, the List component should be implemented like this:

```
<List items={this.state.showInitialList?this.state.initialItems:LabelList} />
```

You can set the showInitialList variable in your state to true whenever fa-plus is clicked.

Comment: I was thinking same and applying it.. let me check first